# ColumnView.MoveFirst Method

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

Hello to all good people. I have a little problem and I need help. How do I focus the first row of the grid, and row by row inserted into the database. My focus is always on the second row. I use devExress grid 
This is an example of my code.

```
Private Sub detailsInsert_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
         ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles detailsInsert_Click_1

    con.Close()
    Try
        GridView1.ClearColumnsFilter()

        con.Open()

        If GridView1.RowCount > 0 Then
            GridView1.MoveFirst()
            'Dim i As Integer
            'i = 1

            For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.RowCount

                com.CommandText = "detInsert N'" & txtID.Text & _
                "',N'" & GridView1.GetRowCellValue(GridView1.FocusedRowHandle, sqlDS.Tables(0).Columns(1).Caption.ToString) & _
                "',N'" & GridView1.GetRowCellValue(GridView1.FocusedRowHandle, sqlDS.Tables(0).Columns(2).Caption.ToString) & _
                "',N'" & GridView1.GetRowCellValue(GridView1.FocusedRowHandle, sqlDS.Tables(0).Columns(3).Caption.ToString) & "'"

                com.ExecuteNonQuery()
                GridView1.MoveNext()

            Next i

        End If

        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute command for each row, you can just iterate through all rows using `GridView.DataRowCount` property. Don't use `GridView.RowCount`, because this property return only visible rows which includes not only data rows, but also includes group rows.
Here is example:

```
Private Sub detailsInsert_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
         ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles detailsInsert_Click_1

    con.Close()
    Try
        GridView1.ClearColumnsFilter()

        con.Open()

        If GridView1.DataRowCount > 0 Then    
            For rowHandle As Integer = 0 To GridView1.DataRowCount - 1

                com.CommandText = "detInsert N'" & txtID.Text & _
                "',N'" & GridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, sqlDS.Tables(0).Columns(1).Caption) & _
                "',N'" & GridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, sqlDS.Tables(0).Columns(2).Caption) & _
                "',N'" & GridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, sqlDS.Tables(0).Columns(3).Caption) & "'"

                com.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next rowHandle    
        End If

        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I had to add this in order to get in position second row. ....

..... com.ExecuteNonQuery()
GridView1.MoveNext() Next rowHandle